# Retrieve array of field's values from MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an `abccollection` collection whose documents look like:

```
{
    id:123
    focusPoint:89652.33
}
```

I want to retrieve all `focusPoint` values so that output looks like:

```
[89652.33, 89999.223, 99666.45, ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a list without duplicates:

```
db.abccollection.distinct("focusPoint")
```

Otherwise, keeping duplicates:

```
db.abccollection.find({}, { _id: 0, focusPoint: 1 }).map((doc) => doc.focusPoint)
```

With that you will retrieve all the documents in the `abccollection` collection and project just the `focusPoint` field. The raw output of that query (before the `map`) will be an array of documents with a single field:

```
[{ focusPoint: 89652.33 }, { focusPoint: 89999.223 }, ...]
```

If you don't want MongoDB to do the [`.map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) in MongoDB, you can also do it in your application.